# Fluent Nhibernate join on non foreign key property

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, left-join

I can't find this anywhere, but it seems pretty trivial. So, please excuse if this is a duplicate.

I have something like:

```
public class Doctor : Entity
{
    ...some other properties here...
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Lawyer : Entity
{
    ...some other properties here...
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return all doctors where there is no email match in the Lawyers table like:

```
select * from Doctors d
where d.Email not in
(select l.Email from Lawyers l where l.Email is not null)
```

or using a join:

```
select d.* from Doctors d
left join Lawyers l on l.Email = d.Email
where l.Email is null
```

The problem is that the Email is of course not set up as a foreign key.  I have no mapped property on the Doctor entity that maps to Lawyer.

What I've tried so far:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Doctor))
    .CreateAlias("Lawyers.Email", "LawyerEmail", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("LawyerEmail"));

return criteria.List<Doctor>();
```

But, I get a "cannot resolve property Lawyer of MyPlatform.MyNamespace.Doctor" error.  Any ideas how to set up my DoctorMap and adjust the criteria tomfoolery to achieve this?

NHibernate for the loss........Entity Framework for the win....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve that with a feature called subquery:

```
// a inner SELECT to return all EMAILs from Lawyer table
var subQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<Lawyer>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Email"));

// the root SELECT to get only these Doctors
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<Doctor>();

// whos email is not in the sub SELECT
criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("Email", subQuery));

// get first 10
var result = criteria
    .SetMaxResults(10)
    .SetFirstResult(0) // paging
    .List<Doctor>();
```

Comment: Awesome, enjoy NHibernate, great tool :)